# What happens if a bean attempts to load the Spring application context in its constructor?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection, infinite-loop

Given the following Spring application context and class A, what happens when you run class A?

applicationContext.xml (in classpath):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
    <bean name="a" class="A"/>
</beans>
```

A.java:

```
class A {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted a related question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923813/how-should-each-class-in-an-application-retrieve-the-spring-application-context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to question your approach, but why is this necessary? If a bean wants a pointer to the application context it's a part of, it should implement [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html). You'll implement a setter and Spring will inject the app context into the bean.

Unless I'm mistaken, your sample code won't actually give that bean a pointer to its app context, it will start up a *new* app context using the same XML file as before. This will in turn create a new bean, which will start *another* app context, etc. — an infinite loop. Try out your code and see whether this happens.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens!  We encountered this error in our own application and I wanted to share our experience in order to help someone else avoid our mistake.

Comment: By the way, thank you for explaining how a bean can obtain a reference to the application context in which it exists.